# How to create filter that takes in multiple ids graphql?

Tags: python, python-requests, graphql

I have the following graphql query:

```
axie_list = []  #f'"{1621247}"'
for ids in tqdm(id_groups[:2]):
    query = {"operationName": "GetAxieDetail",
        "variables": {"axieId": ids},
        "query": "query GetAxieDetail($axieId: IDS!) {\n  axie(axieId: $axieId)  {\n    ...AxieDetail\n  }\n}\n\nfragment AxieDetail on Axie {\n  id\n class\n breedCount\n bodyShape\n  sireClass\n  matronClass\n  stage\n  level\n  \n  parts {\n    ...AxiePart\n  }\n  stats {\n    ...AxieStats\n  }\n}\n\nfragment AxiePart on AxiePart {\n  name\n  type\n}\n\nfragment AxieStats on AxieStats {\n  hp\n  speed\n  skill\n  morale\n}"}
    url = 'https://axieinfinity.com/graphql-server-v2/graphql'
    json_data = requests.post(url, json=query).json()
    axie_list.append(json_data)
```

This query takes in 1 `id` like this `"1621247"` at a time.
I have a group of `ids` in a list and would like to call the `ids` in bulk instead of 1 at a time.
How would something like this look like?

Answer (score 0):

the graphql api doesn't allow doing it friend.